# Create multiple configmaps on kubernetes with using yaml files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a few yaml files that contains some values. I want to read that files while helm deploying and create configmaps for each of them.

I've added config file under the helm charts. ( Same level with templates folder )

[chart structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGOni.png)

And then I've tried to create 'configmap-creator.yaml' which is located under the 'templates' folder.

I simply run 'helm upgrade --install ealpkar --namespace ealpkar --create-namespace .'
It was complete successfully but there is only one configmap which is called 'config2-configmap'. I missed the first one ( config1-configmap )

Here is the 'configmap-creator.yaml'

```
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- range $key, $value := .Files }}
{{- if hasPrefix "config/" $key }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: {{ $key | trimPrefix "config/" | replace ".yaml" "" | replace "_" "-" }}-configmap
data:
{{ $key | trimPrefix "config/" }}: {{ $files.Get $key | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Example of yaml file  which is under 'config' folder;

- config1.yaml

  ```
  dummy_product:
    ip: 10.10.10.10
    port: 22
  ```
- config2.yaml

  ```
  dummy_product_2:
    ip: 10.10.10.20
    port: 22
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your template, adding a separator between objects.

```
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- range $key, $value := .Files }}
{{- if hasPrefix "config/" $key }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: {{ $key | trimPrefix "config/" | replace ".yaml" "" | replace "_" "-" }}-configmap
data:
  {{ $key | trimPrefix "config/" }}: {{ $files.Get $key | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```